# The Möbius Strip diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-topology, projective-space

Are Möbius Strip and $\mathbb{R}P^2$ diffeomorphic?

I really don't know how to approach this, I have tried to construct a diffeomorphism but couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: The Möbius strip has a border. $\Bbb RP^2$ does not.

Comment: In fact, you can build $\Bbb RP^2$ by attaching a disk to the boundary of the Möbius strip.